# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter causing memoryleak

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks, firebaseui

The firebaserecycleradapter in the FirebaseUI 3.1.0 is causing memory leak in my activity.
Following is my Adapter inside onCreateOptionsMenu (Probably the reason)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);


    search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mProgress.show();


            final Query searchQuery = searchDatabaseReference.orderByChild("BusinessName").startAt(query.toUpperCase()).endAt(query.toUpperCase()+"\uf8ff");
            searchQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        noResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        searchRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        LinearLayout searchbgLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchbg_LL);

                        searchbgLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchGetter> options =
                                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SearchGetter>()
                                        .setQuery(searchQuery, SearchGetter.class)
                                        .build();

                        searchRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchGetter, SearchActivity.CardViewHolder>(
                                options

                        ) {
                            @Override
                            public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                        .inflate(R.layout.search_card_layout, parent, false);

                                return new CardViewHolder(view);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position, SearchGetter model) {
                                final String place_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                                holder.setBusinessName(model.getBusinessName());
                                holder.setBusinessAddress(model.getBusinessAddress());

                                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent place_viewIntent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, PlaceActivity.class);
                                        place_viewIntent.putExtra("place_id", place_key);
                                        startActivity(place_viewIntent);

                                    }
                                });
                            }


                        };
                        searchRecyclerView.setAdapter(searchRecyclerAdapter);
                        searchRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        searchRecyclerAdapter.startListening();


                    }else{
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        searchRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });




            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return true;
        }

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And i call **stopListening()** on onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (searchRecyclerAdapter != null){
        searchRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

So how do I:

- Move my adapter to either onStart or onCreate?
- Properly start and stop listening the adapter?

Comment: To avoid memory leaks with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, in onStop() method, besides stop listening the adapter, you should set adapter null to recycler view. In your case: searchRecyclerAdapter.stopListening(); and searchRecylerView.setAdapter(null);  And don't forget to reattach the adapter in onStart or onCreate()  This is the right way to detach a recycler adapter and prevent memory leakes.  I'm writing a comment and not an answer because you asked also how to move the adapter, and although that is the easy part, it requires CODING, and Im sorry I dont have the time.

Comment: @Ramiro Yeah i managed to stop the adapter leaks, but i still would prefer if the adapter is inside either onCeate or onStop in order to properly maintain its lifecycle. I know it looks simple enough but i just cant seem to find a way without messing with the search menu and how i preivously handled it.

Comment: And how did you manage to stop the memory leak?

Comment: i put searchRecyclerAdapter.stopListening(); in both onStop and onDestroy